# I want to remove noise on image sample for handwriting recognition but I get some error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, handwriting-recognition

```
I = imread('data1.jpg');
imshow(I)
J = imnoise(I,'salt%pepper',0.02);
figure,imshow(J)
K = filter2(fspecial('average',3),J)/255;
figure,imshow(K)
L = medfilt2(J,[3,3]);
figure,imshow(L)
```

I got this error when I run above code

```
"??? Error using ==> imnoise>ParseInputs at 231
Unknown noise type: 'salt%pepper'.

Error in ==> imnoise at 85
  [a, code, classIn, classChanged, p3, p4] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});

Error in ==> noisetry at 3
J = imnoise(I,'salt%pepper',0.02);"
```

Comment: try 'salt & pepper' instead of 'salt&pepper'

Comment: I'm voting to close because the problem is caused by a simple typographical error and can't be reproduced

Comment: @BillBokeey i also get the same error. is that have any method to remove noise from an image? can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote 'salt & pepper' and not 'salt % pepper'?

Comment: yes. when i run above code i get this error "? Undefined function or method 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d
real'.

Error in ==> filter2 at 73
        y = conv2(hcol, hrow, x, shape);

Error in ==> noisetry at 5
K = filter2(fspecial('average',3),J)/255;"    @BillBokeey

Comment: @BillBokeey thanks for your attention. but i got the error which i have mention above

Comment: Can you update your question please this is unreadable

Comment: @BillBokeey here are the error                                                                " "Undefined function or method 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d
real'."

Comment: @BillBokeey " "Error in ==> filter2 at 73
        y = conv2(hcol, hrow, x, shape);"

Comment: @BillBokeey "Error in ==> noisetry at 5
K = filter2(fspecial('average',3),J)/255;"

Answer (score 0):

Is your image black&white? If not convert it to B&W (JBW = rgb2gray(I)) and it should work. Function filter works only for 2 dimensional images.

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
imshow(I);
J = imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',0.02);
figure,imshow(J);
JBW = rgb2gray(I);
K = filter2(fspecial('average',3),JBW)/255;
figure,imshow(K);
L = medfilt2(JBW,[3,3]);
figure,imshow(L);
```

Comment: yes my image is black and white. so can you help me to solve all the error? @Agnieszka

Comment: Can you tell me what errors you got after computing the code I gave you? :)

Comment: thanks for helping me :). the code that you had give to me no error. thanks so much. may ask you something? did you familiar with handwriting recognition ? @Agnieszka Mikolajckyk

Comment: Mikolajckyk did hough transform is the best technique for extract the handwriting sample? im little bit confuse

Comment: I don't know what would be the best. You can keep experimenting.